# Getting error why I try to a python program on windows Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a simple program

```
def is_palindrome_v1(s):
   """ (str) --> bool
   Return True if and only if s is a palindrome

   >>> is_palindrome_v1('noon')
   True
   >>> is_palindrome_v1('racecar')
   True
   >>> is_palindrome_v1('dented')
   False
   """"
   return reverse(s) == s

def reverse(s):
    """ (str) --> str
    Return a reversed version of s
    >>> reverse('hello')
    'olleh'
    >>> reverse('a')
    'a'
    """
    rev = ""
    for ch in s:
        rev = ch + rev
    return rev
```

Error that I get when I try to run

```
"SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"
```

Not sure from where I get this error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Your triple-quoted string has one `"` quote too many:

```
 """ (str) --> bool
   Return True if and only if s is a palindrome

   >>> is_palindrome_v1('noon')
   True
   >>> is_palindrome_v1('racecar')
   True
   >>> is_palindrome_v1('dented')
   False
   """"
------^
```